# Slack and Google Admin API integration

Tags: slack, slack-api, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to integrate Slack and Google Admin SDK. Basically, I want a user to be able to book a room through their slack channel. I followed these directions to be able to test post through Slack's API: https://sprint.ly/blog/5-steps-to-a-slack-integration/

My question would be, as I build what my Admin API is supposed to do (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python) where is that script going to live?

I know Slack has "interactive components" and I need to specify a URL to use that. What would that URL be, where do I create it, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Those scripts need to live on a webserver, that can be reached from the Internet. Basically any cloud service will work as long as you can specify a URL to your script.

Alternatively you can open your local webserver through tools like [ngrok](http://ngrok.com/) to the Internet. This approach is also recommend by Slack for developing. (see Slack Tutorials)

See also these answers on the same topic:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47177979/4379151
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46514769/4379151
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46383903/4379151